# Why does DwmGetWindowAttribute with DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS behave unexpectedly when switching monitors?

Tags: c#, c++, winforms, winapi, dwm

When my WinForm application is moved from a primary monitor to a secondary monitor, the bounds (Height and Width of the Window) value returned by these properties and winapi function does not change :

- Form.Bounds
- Form.Size
- GetWindowRect()

But the value returned by `DwmGetWindowAttribute` with `DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS` changes drastically.

**Edits after suggestion from comments:** For instance, in the primary monitor *DwmgetWindowAttribute* returns a rect of width and height `292, 100` and the other values return `306, 107`. This is coherent considering the drop shadow takes up 7 pixels. But when the window is moved to the secondary monitor, *DwmgetWindowAttribute* returns **`437, 150`** and the other methods return the same `306, 107`

In fact both my monitors are of resolution 1920 * 1080 (but the scale differs though if it matters)

**Question**: Why does this happen this way? Is it only me or have anyone else faced similar issues? Ultimately I want to calculate the drop shadow size. Is there any other way?

**To Reproduce:**

If you wish to reproduce this, create a winform project. Allocate console using **AllocConsole()** in the constructor. Add an event handler for `LocationChanged` and add the following code to the event handler:

```
private void AgentMainForm_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      Console.WriteLine("bounds: {0}, {1}", Bounds.Width, Bounds.Height);
      Console.WriteLine("Size: {0}, {1}", Size.Width, Size.Height);
      Console.WriteLine("Window Rect: {0}, {1}", GetSizeWithShadow().Width, GetSizeWithShadow().Height);
      Console.WriteLine("Window Rect: {0}, {1}", GetSizeWithoutShadow().Width, GetSizeWithoutShadow().Height);
}

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hwnd, out RECT lpRect);

[DllImport("dwmapi.dll")]
public static extern int DwmGetWindowAttribute(IntPtr hwnd, int dwAttribute, out RECT pvAttribute, int cbAttribute);

public Size GetSizeWithoutShadow()
{
      RECT regionWithoutShadow;
      IntPtr hWnd = this.Handle;
      if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major < 6) //DwmGetWindowAttribute does not work in XP, compatible only from Vista
      {
            GetWindowRect(hWnd, out regionWithoutShadow);
      }
      else
      {
            if (DwmGetWindowAttribute(hWnd, DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS, out regionWithoutShadow, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(RECT))) != 0)
            {
                 //Handle for failure
            }
      }

      return new Size(regionWithoutShadow.right - regionWithoutShadow.left, regionWithoutShadow.bottom - regionWithoutShadow.top);
}

public Size GetSizeWithShadow()
{
     RECT regionWithoutShadow;
     IntPtr hWnd = this.Handle;

     GetWindowRect(hWnd, out regionWithoutShadow);

     return new Size(regionWithoutShadow.right - regionWithoutShadow.left, regionWithoutShadow.bottom - regionWithoutShadow.top);
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RECT
{
    public int left;
    public int top;
    public int right;
    public int bottom;
}
```

Comment: There is no question in your, well, question. Please read [ask].

Comment: You didn't specify what kind of results you expected and what you measured. `GetWindowRect()` returns logical coordinates, while `DwmGetWindowAttribute()` returns a phisical reference (which take into count the window shadow, as in your code). The computed size of a window is, however, the same. The DPI-awareness of the application can change the results in a High-DPI scaled viewport.

Comment: Actually I'm not expecting any results. Like I said in the question I am just trying to understand why it happens this way. I believe the bound values I observe are irrelevant that's why did not mention them. Anyways I'll add and clarify things up.

Comment: You are surely seeing the side-effects of DPI virtualization.  Which pretends that the window has the size you asked for, but actually automatically scales the window so it doesn't become too small.  DWM values are probably not virtualized.  If you don't want to be lied to then you have to declare your app [to be dpiAware](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13228495/17034), selecting `True/PM` to also suppress per-monitor virtualization.  Hard to deal with in a winforms app because it is now your job to scale the window.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt843498(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You get this answer because your DPI scale is 1.5 on one monitor and 1.0 on the other.  It might be possible to reconcile using [GetDpiForWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdpiforwindow).